# Advice for capturing price time series in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, time-series

I am working with daily stock price time series.
Each day i need to store 4 types of prices (open, high, low, close).

Whatever data structure I use I need to store it sin sequence (preferably a a date or integer as key to later retrieve any of those prices.

Length: variable can be from 2 to 200

I looked into arrays, ArrayLists, Vectors and Maps.
But I still have the problem that they holed pairs, and what I a looking for is to input 1 date or integer and assign to it 4 prices (string each).

Should I use an array and each element would be a class that has 5 members (date plus four kind of prices), then I create ArrayList, instantiate a new class and input is as an element?

Or is there a faster and less complicated way?

Comment: Hi Piyush, yes that seems to be the way but what about very large time series, for example a time series of seconds for a whole week where you can have thousands or hundreds of thousands of points?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class lets say: price with four members:

```
open, high, low, close
```

Create a hash map with date as key and price class as value.

This way all the four members will have unique value for particular day.

All the value can be retrieved with

```
 price.open and so on......
```